# Is it possible and if so, how to enable advanced request filtering on the Cloudflare site?

Tags: firewall, cloudflare, rules, ddos

#### Original question:

**Can we filter and block requests in *Cloudflare* that are incorrect or non-standard, or appear unlikely often from the same *IP* address, even if they are correct?**

**I am particularly interested in filtering requests with *regular expressions*** and the ability to block *IPs* of wrong requests, or at least to automaticly response them with the *400 Bad Request* response code, as it is possible using *mod_security* in the *Apache* server.

**The second important thing is the ability to filter out extremely frequent requests that appear from the same *IP* address (even if they are correct)**. For example, I would like to be able to block *IP* addresses at the *Cloudflare* level, which have made more than 1000 requests per minute.

**Does *Cloudflare* give us such an opportunity?**

**If so, what conditions do I have to meet and where can I do it in the *Cloudflare panel*?** If possible, please give me **precise guidelines**.

**All this matters in the context of defense against *DDOS* attacks.**

#### An update to explain the context in which I ask this question:

**I am a programmer who needs to implement a solution to protect against *DDOS* attacks.** So far my program written in *Python* has used the *Apache access_log* in combination with *Apache mod_security* and other services such as *firewall*.

**Now I have the opportunity to use *Cloudflare* and that's why I'm asking.**

Maybe, thanks to *Cloudflare*, I will turn out my program, because it will be unnecessary and the solution will be able to do exactly the same as now, but at an earlier stage (the request will not reach the web server), but maybe (depending on the answer), I will have to stay the old way, or **maybe I will be able to slightly improve the program and consumption of web server resources by eliminating it with *mod_security* or in some other way.**

*I am asking for help and advice.*

*Thank you in advance!*

Comment: Does Cloudflare have no technical support at all?

Comment: @Rob does the technical support rule out the possibility of asking questions on stackoverflow? For some reason there are several thousand questions asked with the tag `cloudflare`, right?

Comment: Your questions are asking "how does Cloudflare work" which means you are not asking Cloudflare for tech support which makes me question the quality of Cloudflare's support of their own product. Stack Overflow is not a tech support forum for any commercial product but your question is about configuration and administration of a networking product and that is strictly off topic here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand why this question received negative points and was additionally nominated for close. I think that the answer can be useful to many users, including those who are just considering using the Cloudflare service. I guess we have to help each other, not to interrupt?

Comment: @Rob my friend, I know the quoted by you website and I agree that this question may be on the edge of the 6th point: *"Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure are off-topic for Stack Overflow ..."*, however, its further part: *"unless they have somehow programming or programming"* is already defending me, because I am a programmer who must implement a solution to protect against DDOS attacks. So far my program has used `mod_security` and other things, but now I have the opportunity to use Cloudflare and that's why I'm asking. I will add it in question soon, OK?

Comment: Besides, if nobody could ask for a CloudFlare stackoverflow, I think that we would not have allowed tags associated with this service, right?

Comment: For your information @Rob, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> filtering requests with regular expressions

Use [Firewall Rules](https://blog.cloudflare.com/announcing-firewall-rules/).

> ability to filter out extremely frequent requests that appear from the same IP address

Use [Rate-Limiting](https://www.cloudflare.com/rate-limiting/).

> please give me precise guidelines.

Contact [Cloudflare Support](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172476-Contacting-Cloudflare-Support) for specific configuration to meet your requirements.